# How to do IBOutlets in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, iboutlet

I have done one iPhone app in Objective-C.  When I want to link a Label to some data in that I would declare it like this:

```
@interface CityDetailViewController : UIViewController {
UILabel *cityName;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *cityName;
```

And then when the CityDetailViewController object is created in code I would set the city name like this `[self.cityView.cityName setText:city.name];`

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to do this in MonoTouch.
I tried manually creating the Outlets through Interface Builder and I tried adding this code that I found in the .designer.cs file from another project:

```
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("headlineLabel")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel headlineLabel {
        get {
            return ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel)(this.GetNativeField("headlineLabel")));
        }
        set {
            this.SetNativeField("headlineLabel", value);
        }
    }
```

And I've tried a combination of both of those things.
They don't work.
The closest I can get is to actually apply the Outlet using Interface Builder, but when my View is declared I get this error:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key headlineLabel.

So I'm completely at a loss.
Can someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pretty sure that I've figured it out so I'll post the process here for others to look at:

**Step 1)** Start with your empty View like this:
[image: step 1]
<sub>(source: [jamespwright.com](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/screengrabs/7f2b8d35406e98ee5a00a81c6346e373.PNG))</sub>

**Step 2)** Add a UILabel Control to your View:
[image: step 2]
<sub>(source: [jamespwright.com](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/screengrabs/d757c579238ffc27acabb69c55460071.PNG))</sub>

**Step 3)** Select "File's Owner":
[image: step 3]
<sub>(source: [jamespwright.com](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/screengrabs/42900214063dbbc44cd4dbc2813d64eb.PNG))</sub>

**Step 4)** Select the Identity Inspector (CMD + 4) and add a new Class Outlet:
[image: step 4]
<sub>(source: [jamespwright.com](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/screengrabs/109318382a72ac9edad2bcd24e6a4b9f.PNG))</sub>

**Step 5)** Select the Connections Inspector (CMD + 2) and you should see your new Class Outlet there:
[image: step 5]
<sub>(source: [jamespwright.com](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/screengrabs/2a2f9f4f0cc6680e7dd8c47cabba7e24.PNG))</sub>

**Step 6)** Drag the connection to your Label on your View.

**Step 7)** Inside your code you populate it by typing `myLabel.Text = "My Label!"`

Hopefully that will help someone else out in the future.